# Moose empty value for typed attributes

Tags: perl, moose

Is there some way in Moose to specify that I want an attribute to have a specific type, but also allow there to be a null value (undef?).

For example I am writing a simple implementation of a Linked List and have a Node class where the `next` and `prev` pointers are required to be of type `Node` (this is probably what you would expect)

```
package Node;
{
   use Moose; 

   has 'value' => (
      is  => 'rw',
      isa => 'Any', # Nodes can be of any type
   );

   has 'prev' => (
      is        => 'rw',
      isa       => 'Node',
      predicate => 'has_prev',
   );

   has 'next' => (
      is        => 'rw',
      isa       => 'Node',
      predicate => 'has_next',
   );

}
```

But I was hoping to use a sentinel, empty node stored at the head of the list to mark the head, instead of an actual element of the list. So a list of elements [1, 2, 3] would actually look like:

```
EMPTY -> 1 -> 2 -> 3
```

I was hoping to be able to specify a empty value (like undef) for the `next` and `prev` pointers, but when I create an empty `Node` in my List class:

```
package List;
{
   use Moose;

   has 'head' => (
      is      => 'rw',
      isa     => 'Node',
      # empty head node
      default => sub { 
         Node->new( value => undef, next => undef, prev => undef ); 
      }, 
   );
```

Moose complains because `undef` is not of type `Node`.

Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Maybe[type]` syntax to allow the type or `undef`. For your example:

```
   has 'head' => (
      is      => 'rw',
      isa     => 'Maybe[Node]',
      # empty head node
      default => sub { 
         Node->new( value => undef, next => undef, prev => undef ); 
      }
   );
```

Comment: It's documented here: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod#THE_TYPES

Answer (score 1):

The next:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

package Node {
   use Moose; 
   has 'value' => ( is  => 'rw');
   has 'prev' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Undef|Node', predicate => 'has_prev', default=>undef );
   has 'next' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Undef|Node', predicate => 'has_next', default=>undef );
}

package List {
   use Moose;
   has 'head' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Node', default => sub { Node->new() } );
}

package main;
use Data::Dumper;

my $list = List->new();
say Dumper $list;
```

prints:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'head' => bless( {
                                    'next' => undef,
                                    'prev' => undef
                                  }, 'Node' )
               }, 'List' );
```

The  [Moose::Manual::Types](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod) says for the basic hier:

> ```
>       Undef     <---- undefined
>       Defined
>           Value
>               Str
>                   Num
>                       Int
>                   ClassName <---- Class name
>                   RoleName
> ```

and later in the section [TYPE UNIONS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod#TYPE_UNIONS) says:

> Moose allows you to say that an attribute can be of two or more
>   disparate types. For example, we might allow an Object or FileHandle:
>
> has 'output' => (
>         is  => 'rw',
>         isa => 'Object | FileHandle',   );

As others already says, here is a `Maybe[Something]` too, I haven't idea what is better, but  the `Something | SomethingOther` looks more "perlish" (IMHO). ;)

Answer (score 0):

The authors prefer `Undef|Node` over `Maybe[Node]`.

```
has 'prev' => (
   is        => 'rw',
   isa       => 'Undef|Node',
   predicate => 'has_prev',
);
```

Comment: Which authors? (of Moose?) and can you link to where you found this?

Comment: All I could find was this note in the [`Moose::Util::TypeConstraints` manual](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose::Util::TypeConstraints#Default-Type-Constraints): "The Undef type constraint for the most part works correctly now, but edge cases may still exist, please use it sparingly."

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, Of Moose, In a communication me. Maybe in a bug report I filed?